# How can I change the vertical range of the Dygraph range selector?

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

Is it possible to change the minimum and maximum of the y-axis for the **range selector** in Dygraphs?

Comment: http://dygraphs.com/options.html#valueRange

Comment: valueRange only changes the vertical range of the main graph. I'm looking for the vertical range of the range selector.

Comment: Could you upload a jsfiddle with your dygraphs scenario? I think it is not possible directly using the options of dygraphs, but maybe we can figure out an alternative that solves your problem

Comment: Yes, that is [hard-coded](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/blob/f6e73ea983b61b50a6152c98a9945725eb45edb2/src/plugins/range-selector.js#L548-L549). But adding an option would be a reasonable [pull request](http://dygraphs.com/changes.html)